# Klarna Payment gateway integration with WebFlow project

Tags: javascript, webflow, klarna

**Klarna** has been one of the most famous payment processing way that we have been using many projects.

Now a days I am **asked to make a project using** [WebFlow](https://webflow.com/).  But there are **not many resources out there** to make out a checkout form working with Klarna in webflow.

what I have seen so far there are three ways out there?

1. Download the code of webflow convert into react and use JS plugin of Klarna.
2. Use [mollie](https://www.mollie.com/en/pricing/) with webflow components! but it is not an option.
3. Integrate whole Shoppify button in Webflow and use that Klarna from Shoppify in your webflow checkout (extra work and not cheap)

So bottom line question is like this:

**Is there any way to make the KLARNA integration possible with webflow like other integrations**